# Simple invariants to detect concordance in general 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Let $Y$ be a closed, connected, orientable 3-manifold.  We call to oriented knots $K_1, K_2$ in $Y$ (smoothly) concordant if there is a smoothly, properly embedded annulus in $Y \times I$ such that the boundary components of the annulus are in $Y \times \{0\}$ and $Y \times \{1\}$ and are $K_1$ and $K_2$ (with there respective orientations).

If you are walking along and explicitly given a 3-manifold (say by a framed link) and a pair of knots $K_1$ and $K_2$ and you are asked if they are concordant, after checking that they are the same class in $\pi_1$, what do you do?  Specifically what if $K_2$ is just the unknot - what sorts of simple invariants can I try and compute to see if $K_1$ is not null concordant?

I've seen a couple of papers floating around but I was wondering what kinds of "classical" invariants there are for this sort of problem.  For example if $Y = S^3$, the first things I might try would be the Arf invariant and the signature.

As an example, maybe take $Y = S^1 \times S^2$ and take $K_1$ as one of the components of the Whitehead link (where the other component is given 0-framing thus giving $S^1 \times S^2$), and take $K_2$ to be the unknot.

Comment: Jen Hom has quite a few papers on knot concordant and slice knot related stuffs. You can have a look at those. there are some invariant like $\tao$-invariant, $\epsilon$-invariant etc. If I am not wrong, Jen Hom proved that $K$ is slice(smoothly) then $\epsilon(K)=0$.

Comment: But all those results are for $S^3$

Comment: @Anubhav I also don't know if anything from HFK can be considered too elementary.

Comment: @MikeMiller I agreed. Top of my head I don't remember exactly, but Milnor had some results in early 60's related with some lower central series.

Comment: In the specific case of null-homologous knots, you can use any invariant of (rational or integral, say) homology cobordism for 3-manifold, by doing surgeries and branched covers. Specifically, say $K_1 \subset Y$ is the unknot; then $-p/q$-surgery along $K_2$ is integrally homology cobordant to $Y\# L(p,q)$; likewise, if $\Sigma_r(K_2)$ is rationally homology cobordant to $Y^{\#r}$.

Comment: Also, for topological concordance there is a nice invariant due to Schneiderman (*Algebraic linking numbers of knots in 3–manifolds*, AG&T, 2003).

Comment: @MarcoGolla Thanks, do you know of any reference for that homology cobordism statement? I was not aware of anything like that

Comment: @user101010: for surgery cobordism, a paper came out yesterday with the proof of the integer homology cobordism (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.10178, Section 7), so I do have a reference at hand. As for the branched cover statement, just take the cover of the cylinder branched over the concordance. (There are probably homological assumptions about which prime powers you can use, but I don't have a general statement.)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the relaxation of the closed condition so that $ \partial Y $ is permitted to be a surface, there is a very simple concordance obstruction for knots in a thickening of the boundary, due to Kauffman.

Let $ \partial Y = \Sigma_g $, a closed orientable surface of genus g. Given a knot $ K \hookrightarrow \Sigma_g \times I $, take its regular projection to $ \Sigma_g $: the result is a knot diagram on $ \Sigma_g $, denoted $ D $.

Pick a crossing, $ c $, of $ D $. Leave $ c $ from any outgoing arc, and traverse $ D $ until you return to $ c $, counting the number of other crossing you passed through. If you passed through an even number of crossings, declare $ c $ to be *even*, otherwise delcare it *odd*. Repeat this for the other crossings of $ D $.

Denote by $ J ( D ) $ the sum of the signs of the odd crossings. Kauffman shows this is an invariant of $ K $, and we may define $ J ( K ) = J ( D ) $ [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405049)]. It is shown in [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07324),[3](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~boden/preprints/hub35.pdf)] that if $ J ( K ) \neq 0 $ then $ K $ is not concordant in $ Y \times I $ to the trivial knot. Equivalently, $ K $ does not bound a disc in $ Y \times I $ (it does not bound a disc in any $3$-manifold with boundary $ \Sigma_g $, in fact).

This extends automatically to obstructing concordances between two non-trivial knots $ K_1 $ and $ K_2 $, in the case when $ \partial Y = \Sigma_g \sqcup \Sigma_{g'} $, $ K_1 \hookrightarrow \Sigma_g $, $ K_2 \hookrightarrow \Sigma_{g'} $. If $ J ( K_1 ) \neq J ( K_2 ) $ then $ K_1 $ is not concordant in $ Y \times I $ to $ K_2 $.